# What do you call a person who "shuts down" ideas?

Tags: single-word-requests

You know, the kind of person who you tell stuff like "I really want to go to this thing" and they point out everything wrong with it.

Comment: "Wet blanket" is the first term that comes to mind.

Answer (score 6):

Such a person might be a ***[naysayer](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/naysayer)***, "a person who habitually expresses negative or pessimistic views" (TFD)

Answer (score 5):

A **[wet blanket](https://www.google.com/search?q=define%20wet%20blanket&oq=define%20wet%20blanket&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l4.3638j0j4&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=91&ie=UTF-8)**:

> a person who spoils other people's fun by failing to join in with or
>   by disapproving of their activities.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of possibles depending on context - party-pooper, grinch, killjoy, spoilsport, grouch, wet-blanket, eeyore, misery-guts ...

Answer (score 2):

A [**party pooper**](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/party-pooper)?

> a person who hasn't the interest or vitality to participate actively in a social party and whose mood, attitude, or personality lessens others' enjoyment; killjoy.

Or for that matter a [**killjoy**](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/killjoy)?

> : a person who spoils other people's fun or enjoyment

Answer (score 2):

A [naysayer](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/naysayer):

> a person who says something will not work or is not possible : a
>   person who denies, refuses, or opposes something

Examples:

> There are always naysayers who say it can't be done.
>   Those naysayers who attack the integrity of the entire judicial system

Comment: "Naysayer"  has been proposed already,  how is your answer an improvement?

Comment: @A.P. To be fair, despite the apparent difference in times I think our postings were effectively simultaneous.

Comment: Oh, in that case let me retract the downvote and upvote it instead.

Comment: Yup, they were.

Answer (score 1):

A [Debbie Downer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Debbie_Downer), taken from the name of the title character of a series of noted Saturday Night Live sketches.

Answer (score 1):

A ***negative*** person.

> NEGATIVE
>
> a :  lacking positive qualities; especially :  disagreeable
>
> b : marked by features of hostility, withdrawal, or pessimism that hinder
> or oppose constructive treatment or development 
>  [M-W](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/negative)
>
> *Quotes About Negative People* [Good Reads](http://www.goodreads.com/quotes/tag/negative-people)

Answer (score 1):

Consider **negativist**:

> negativism: A habitual attitude of skepticism or resistance to the suggestions, orders, or instructions of others.

([American Heritage Dictionary](https://ahdictionary.com/word/search.html?q=negativism))

Also, **spoilsport** might work:

> someone who spoils other people’s fun

([Longman](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/spoilsport))

Answer (score 0):

A [Stick in the Mud].[1](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/stick-in-the-mud) It's a person who clings to the past or the way things have always been done and therefore not willing to listen to or try new ideas.